# Setup and use a cookie-based session in Pedestal

Tags: session, clojure, middleware, ring, pedestal

I'd appreciate a basic Pedestal example of how to (1) setup cookies that survive server restarts and (2) use cookie-based sessions; in particular how to get and set values.

I'm a little surprised not to find an example that uses `ring.middleware.session/wrap-session` (source code here: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj).

### Setup

According to this [Pedestal sample code for using Ring middleware](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/samples/ring-middleware/src/ring_middleware/service.clj), there are two key things to add to your `service.clj`. First, define the session interceptor:

```
; aliases for namespace :require
[io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares :as middlewares]
[ring.middleware.session.cookie :as cookie]

(definterceptor session-interceptor
  (middlewares/session {:store (cookie/cookie-store)}))
```

The sample code has this caveat, however:

> In this example code we do not specify the secret with which the
>   session data is encrypted prior to being sent back to the
>   browser. This has two consequences, the first being that we need to
>   use the same interceptor instance throughout the service so that the
>   session data is readable and writable to all paths. The second
>   consequence is that session data will become unrecoverable when the
>   server process is ended. Even though the browser retains the
>   cookie, it is not unrecoverable cipher-text and the session
>   interceptor will treat it as non-existent.

How do I overcome the above limitations?

And, second, add the `session-interceptor` to your routes (the following is my example code):

```
(defroutes routes
  [[["/"
     {:get [:root root/index]}
     ^:interceptors [session-interceptor
                     (body-params/body-params)
                     bootstrap/html-body]]]]
```

### Use (Get and Set)

I know that the setup steps above cause the Ring middleware to add a `:session` key to the request map.  So getting is easy: `(:session request)`. But how and where do I add to the session? An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, to answer some of my questions:

Specifying a key means that the cookie-backed sessions will be re-readable after a server restart, as mentioned by [Compojure/Ring: Why doesn't a session with cookie-store survive a server restart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501111). Here is some code that shows how:

```
; (:require [crypto.random :as random])
(def the-key (random/bytes 16)) ; run once
{:store (cookie-store {:key the-key})}
```

When it comes to changing the value of a session:

> “To set the value of :session, just pass it along with your response. If you don’t need the session changed, leave :session out of your response. If you want to actually clear the session, pass nil as the value of the :session key.” (from: [Luke VanderHart and Ryan Neufeld. “Clojure Cookbook.”](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook))

Comment: Did you get any further? It would be wonderful if you could post a working code snippet.