# Remember Me functionality in Clojure Friend

Tags: session, cookies, clojure, session-cookies

I am using Friend for authentication/authorization in a Clojure Ring application. I am trying to persist session data into a cookie via 'Remember Me' functionality, so that it can survive e.g. server restarts. My handler definition is:

```
(def secured-routes
  (-> app-routes
      (friend/authenticate friend-param-map)
      (wrap-defaults (-> site-defaults
                         (assoc-in [:security :anti-forgery] false)
                         (assoc :session {:store (cookie-store {:key "16-byte-secret"})
                                          :cookie-name "TestCookie"
                                          :cookie-attrs {:max-age 1800}})
                         (assoc :cookies true)))
      wrap-json-params))
```

What else do I need to write to make it work? Do I need to create a cookie first in one of the `app-routes` handlers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are already aware of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501111/compojure-ring-why-doesnt-a-session-with-cookie-store-survive-a-server-restart). Anyway as far as I recall your best chance is to use [wrap-session](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj#L74)

Something like this should work (sorry not tested)

```
(def secured-routes
  (-> app-routes
      (friend/authenticate friend-param-map)
      (wrap-session {:cookie-attrs {:max-age 3600} :cookie-name "TestCookie" } )
      (wrap-defaults (-> site-defaults
                         (assoc-in [:security :anti-forgery] false)))
      wrap-json-params))
```